# Is there any way to convert a .py script file (on Python) to LaTeX code?

Tags: python, pythontex

In the same way you can convert a jupyter notebook file to `.tex` file by using `nbconvert` package, I was wondering if there exist an equivalent way to do the same stuff but with `.py` script file as input.

The behavior would be like:

1. Program takes a `.py` file as input.
2. Program returns a `.tex` file as output (with its highlights, indents, colors, etc).

Comment: The [listings package](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) can include Python (and other languages) in the pdf output.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by outputting a .tex file with highlights, indents, colors, etc.  TeX files are pure text, which doesn't have those things.

Comment: I mean that the .tex output file should include the necessary latex commands in order to replicate the whole format of .py file. can listings package deal with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I get what you're asking for.

You can use the `inputminted` command of the `minted` package to generate a *PDF file* (not a .tex) from a Python script.

For example, if your main LaTeX file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\inputminted{python}{script.py}
\end{document}
```

and your `script.py` file is:

```
# Python program to find the factorial of a number provided by the user.
# change the value for a different result
num = 7
# To take input from the user
#num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1
# check if the number is negative, positive or zero
if num < 0:
   print("Sorry, factorial does not exist for negative numbers")
elif num == 0:
   print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
else:
   for i in range(1,num + 1):
       factorial = factorial*i
   print("The factorial of",num,"is",factorial)
```

you can get the following PDF:

[image]

---

**Update**

Just read your comment to Teepeemm.
You can convert your `.py` file into a `.ipynb` using something like [p2j](https://github.com/remykarem/python2jupyter), and then into `.tex` using the `nbconvert` function of `jupyter`.

Comment: Thanks, but i get the following output error when compiling (on TexStudio) --> Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.
Do you know what is this?

Comment: Don't know. I'm using Linux and the terminal directly. You need to have `pygmentize` installed. Perhaps the `listing` package, suggested by Teepeemm, can do the same without it.

Comment: Ok I will search for information, ;)

Comment: Sure that is right. --shell-escape alleviates some restrictions on TeX and allows it to use scripts in your PATH environment variable. I dont know TeXstudio; In TeXworks, there is a list of compilation-tools, and -shell-escape is one of command line arguments for compilation.